# Uniform convergence of alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> If the sequence of functions $f_{n}: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is such that $f_{1} \geq ... \geq f_{k} \geq ...$ and $f_{n} \longrightarrow 0$ uniformly in $X$. Prove that $\displaystyle \sum(-1)^{n}f_{n}$ uniformly converges in $X$

Since $f_{n}$ is uniformly convergent, the convergence of $f$ not dependes of $x$. Thus, is the proof reduced to the Leibniz test?

Comment: If $1=f_1≥f_2≥\dots ≥ 1$ are the constant 1 function then $f_n \to 1$ uniformly but $\sum(-1)^n f_n$ does not exist even pointwise

Comment: @CalvinKhor, sorry.. $f_{n} \longrightarrow 0$. Already corrected.

Comment: Is $X$ a metric space?

Comment: @Sisyphus yeah, $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Use $\left| \sum_n^m (-1)^k f_k \right| = f_n - (f_{n+1} - f_{n+2}) - \ldots \leqslant f_n$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In particular, $f_n\to 0$ pointwise and $f_n\geq 0$, so $S(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf_n(x)$ can be defined as a function by the alternating series test.
Moreover, the truncation error for only taking $N$ terms is bounded by the $N+1$th term. This can be seen as follows: let $S_N$ be the $N$th partial sum, and let $g_n = f_{2n} - f_{2n-1}$. Then $g_n≤0$, so $S_{2N} = \sum_{n=1}^N g_n$ must decrease to $S$. Similarly, $S_{2N+1}$ must increase towards $S$. Therefore, for any $N$,
$$ S_{2N+1} ≤ S_{2N+3}  ≤ S ≤ S_{2N+2} ≤ S_{2N}$$
and it follows (by $f_n$'s uniform convergence) that
$$ |S(x) - S_{N}(x)| ≤ |f_{N+1}(x)| ≤ \|f_{N+1}\|_{\infty,X} \to 0.$$
Hence, $S_N$ converges uniformly to $S$.

Comment: @ShyGuy and edit approvers: I disagree. 1) you ruined the English of ‘In particular’. 2) it’s clear from the question that the functions converge uniformly. 3) For the particular point you edited, only pointwise convergence is needed. I clearly noted where uniform convergence of the $f_n$s is used (the last step). I’ll wait a little to see if someone wants to discuss further and if not I’ll revert

Comment: I agree about the "in particular" bit and was considering removing it but I wanted to keep the edits at a minimum. I can say that as someone who was very recently introduced to this subject, it took me a couple of minutes to figure out that the final $\leq$ in the last inequality stems from $f_n$'s *uniform* convergence, and think it might be beneficial to state that somewhere, even if it is obvious within the context of the question (and I agree that it is; but I think explicitly stating that somewhere would contribute to the answer's clarity).

Comment: Leaving this up to you to decide if you'd rather revert or implement my advice, and how. :)
(To emphasize: looking at this answer, I thought initially that you were implying that pointwise convergence was sufficient. Clearly you weren't and I thought that was worth a small mention, in some form.)

Comment: I've modified it to what it was previously but with a small clarification as I've suggested. Does this seem fine?

Comment: @ShyGuy yeah thats much better IMO, have approved it

Comment: Thanks! I agree. Sorry for the initial clumsy edit.